# PhalconPHP can not parse my query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phalcon

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT post.* FROM post ORDER BY post.timestamp DESC) as post
GROUP BY post.topic_id
ORDER BY post.timestamp DESC, post.position
LIMIT 15
```

Phalcon is throwing following error when trying to execute the query above. The query itself works fine on default sql.

```
Syntax error, unexpected token (, near to ' SELECT post.* FROM post ORDER BY post.timestamp DESC ) as post GROUP BY post.topic_id ORDER BY post.timestamp DESC, post.position LIMIT 15', when parsing: SELECT * FROM ( SELECT post.* FROM post ORDER BY post.timestamp DESC ) as post GROUP BY post.topic_id ORDER BY post.timestamp DESC, post.position LIMIT 15 (162)
```

Using the following PHP-Code (for testing):

```
$sql = <<< QUERY
    *query*
QUERY;

$query = $this->modelsManager->createQuery($sql);
$result = $query->execute();
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Using a subquery won't perform that well. Check out [this article on selecting the one row per group](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/).

Comment: I'll take a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create view, to keep already reverse sorted virtual table:

   CREATE VIEW v_latest_posts AS SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY timestamp DESC
2. use view in select:

   SELECT * FROM v_latest_posts
   GROUP BY topic_id
   ORDER BY timestamp DESC, position ASC
   LIMIT 15

Comment: Because he wants the latest post per topic. Your query is going to give a random post per topic.

Comment: Thank you, but I doesn't seems to work. Phalcons PHQL-Language-Parser searchs now for a model called v_latest_posts. But found a solution, see here: http://puu.sh/j79B1/c9846608de.png